# Automapper: binding a concrete class "from" multiple interface

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map a class (`TrackingKeyStatic<T>`) using c# and automapper.
`TrackingKeyStatic<T>` has the interface IBatchProcessing is inherited from `Trackingkey<T>` which has the interface ITrackingKey.
So by definition `TrackingKeyStatic<T>` is IBatchProcessing and ITrackingKey.

Automapper working fine with only one interface (IBatchProcessing)
But can't be mapped/be detect with interface ITrackingKey

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate https://dotnetfiddle.net/TO21PI

So the question is how can I map source with two interface to a concrete `type<T>`?

- I've tried with this config, and it didn't work (which is the problem)

  ```
     cfg.CreateMap<ITrackingKey, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>()
  ```
- I've tried to change the automapper config for

  ```
     cfg.CreateMap<TrackingKeyStatic<NotReleventClassForThisExample>, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>()
  ```

As demonstrate in Method TestWitTrackingKeyStaticAsSource_WORKING() its working just fine. But I can't really make a mapping for each subclass

- I've tried to use method like .Include or .IncludeAllDerived, it didn't work, but I'm not quite sure if I need to use them here? Maybe I did it wrong?

Here's the unit tests I wrote for this question

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestWithItrackingAsSource_NOTWORKING()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<ITrackingKey, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.TrackingKey, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.NewTrackingKey));
                cfg.CreateMap<IBatchProcessing, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Skip, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Skip))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Take, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Take))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Total, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Total));
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var source = new TrackingKeyStatic<NotReleventClassForThisExample>()
            {
                Skip = 10,
                Take = 50,
                Total = 123456,
                NewTrackingKey = 987654
            };
            var actual = mapper.Map<MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>(source);
            Assert.AreEqual(10, actual.Skip);//ok
            Assert.AreEqual(50, actual.Take);//ok
            Assert.AreEqual(123456, actual.Total);//ok
            Assert.AreEqual(987654, actual.TrackingKey);//failed
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestWitTrackingKeyStaticAsSource_WORKING()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<TrackingKeyStatic<NotReleventClassForThisExample>, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.TrackingKey, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.NewTrackingKey));
                cfg.CreateMap<IBatchProcessing, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Skip, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Skip))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Take, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Take))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Total, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Total));
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var source = new TrackingKeyStatic<NotReleventClassForThisExample>()
            {
                Skip = 10,
                Take = 50,
                Total = 123456,
                NewTrackingKey = 987654
            };
            var actual = mapper.Map<MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>(source);
            Assert.AreEqual(10, actual.Skip);//ok
            Assert.AreEqual(50, actual.Take);//ok
            Assert.AreEqual(123456, actual.Total);//ok
            Assert.AreEqual(987654, actual.TrackingKey);//work fine
        }
    }
    public interface ITrackingKey
    {
        int NewTrackingKey { get; set; }
        List<object> Records { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IBatchProcessing
    {
        int Skip { get; set; }
        int Take { get; set; }
        int Total { get; set; }
    }
    public class TrackingKey<T> : ITrackingKey
    {
        private List<object> _records;

        public int NewTrackingKey { get; set; }

        public List<T> Records  //not relevant for question, it just for implementing interface
        {
            get { return _records?.Cast<T>()?.ToList(); }
            set { _records = value?.Cast<object>()?.ToList(); }
        }

        List<object> ITrackingKey.Records //not relevant for question, it just for implementing interface
        {
            get { return _records; }
            set { _records = value; }
        }
    }
    public class TrackingKeyStatic<T> : TrackingKey<T>, IBatchProcessing
    {
        public int Skip { get; set; }
        public int Take { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyEntitiesDbFirstModel
    {
        public int Skip { get; set; }
        public int Take { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public int TrackingKey { get; set; }
    }

    public class NotReleventClassForThisExample { public int MyProperty { get; set; }}
}
```

Comment: Create two maps, and use the same object twice.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by create two maps? 
isnt it what i'm doing?
             cfg.CreateMap<ITrackingKey, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>([...]);
             cfg.CreateMap<IBatchProcessing, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>([...])

Comment: Does it not work to add an extra line mapper.Map<ITrackingKey,MyEntitiesDbModel>(source, actual);?

Comment: var actual = mapper.Map<MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>(source);


var actual2 = mapper.Map<ITrackingKey, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>(source, actual);

Sadly, this is not doing the trick :( You can see the modification here https://dotnetfiddle.net/m9g29G

Comment: Yep, I was on mobile earlier. This is interesting problem - may actually just not work out of the box with automapper. I've added you a potential answer and well done on the question though - very well prepared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working with a small "hacky" wrapper method:

```
    public static MyEntitiesDbFirstModel MapToMyDbModel<T>(TrackingKeyStatic<T> trackingKey, IMapper mapper)
    {
        var interimTypeObject = new TrackingKey<T>()
        {
            NewTrackingKey = trackingKey.NewTrackingKey
        };

        var actual = mapper.Map<MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>(trackingKey);
        mapper.Map<ITrackingKey, MyEntitiesDbFirstModel>(interimTypeObject, actual);

        return actual;
    }
```

Here's the fiddle for it - https://dotnetfiddle.net/XAjQB4

You may be able get rid of uglyness further - it seems that AutoMapper is not able to choose the correct map here when you use `TrackingKeyStatic<T>` but has no problems doing `TrackingKey<T>`.

Comment: You don't get to choose the source type used when matching a map. The source runtime type is always used. So I don't see a cleaner way without changing _something_ about the structure of the types involved.